# Is it possible to track only slow requests with appstats?

Tags: google-app-engine

Our application processes several dozens of requests per second and small portion of them takes significantly more time to process than others. We are interested to 'profile' those slow requests, however appstats seems to keep just small window of processed requests, so the ones we are interested in fades out very fast. Is it possible to configure appstats somehow to keep log of just requests taking more time than specified threshold ?

Comment: Not an answer, but I think this would be a good feature request. Please put it in the tracker. Also, if you read the source for appstats/recording.py in the SDK you can probably figure out how to do this yourself, until trhe feature is implemented!

Comment: thx. Guido. It's feature request [8332](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8332)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A detailed list of configuration options regarding Appstats, is presented at [Sample Appstats Configuration Example](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/appstats/sample_appengine_config.py) in the GAE SDK. Based on this file, it seems that currently it's not possible to capture requests based on their execution time.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no built in mechanism for this.

You could add it yourself by monkeypatching the [end_recording method](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/appstats/recording.py#1426), or the Recorder.save method.